# How can I make the color range symmetric around zero in Paraview?

Tags: visualization, paraview

I often use diverging colormaps (like the Paraview default "cool-to-warm") with a color range that is symmetric around zero, e.g. to visualize areas of tensile (red) and compressive (blue) stress with stress-free areas in a neutral color.

For this, I have to adjust the "Custom Data Range" by hand every time I load a new data set.

Can I automate this process? Maybe with a macro?

Unsymmetric color range:

[image: Unsymmetric color range]

Symmetric color range (what I want):

[image: Symmetric color Range]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a Paraview macro that sets a symmetric color range based on the color range that is currently set (maximum absolute value).

Note that the macro does not rescale the range based on the data. So **if you load new data and want to adjust, you have to "Rescale to Range" first**. The macro has no effect if the range is already symmetric.

Save the following code in a Python script, e.g. "SymmetrizeColorRangeMax.py" and then in Paraview: "Macros" → "Import new macro...".

```
from paraview.simple import *

source = GetActiveSource()
view = GetActiveView()
display = GetDisplayProperties(source, view=view)
cname = display.ColorArrayName[1]
ctf = GetColorTransferFunction(cname)

cmin = ctf.RGBPoints[0]
cmax = ctf.RGBPoints[-4]
cmaxabs = max(abs(cmin), abs(cmax))

ctf.RescaleTransferFunction(-cmaxabs, cmaxabs)
```